# How to integrate Webpack's bootstrap with IE8 that has Object.defineProperty?

Tags: javascript, webpack, internet-explorer-8, babeljs

Essentially Webpack adds some code at beginning of the bundle:

```
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
```

Which is causing an error with IE8 (`Object.defineProperty` is undefined). I am using babel `es2015-loose` preset as a loader so that it should not be a problem (it is generating stub for it if I want to use it somewhere else):

```
function _defineProperty(obj, key, value) { if (key in obj) { Object.defineProperty(obj, key, { value: value, enumerable: true, configurable: true, writable: true }); } else { obj[key] = value; } return obj; }

var obj = (_obj = {}, _defineProperty(_obj, "x" + foo, "heh"), _defineProperty(_obj, "y" + bar, "noo"), _defineProperty(_obj, "foo", "foo"), _defineProperty(_obj, "bar", "bar"), _obj);
```

My all code (special repository to reproduce this problem) is [here, pointing to particular commit](https://github.com/puradawid/webpack-babeling-issue/tree/dc2ac3a93af526fdc02d56edc432153d520710b9). You can check this by running `validate.sh` assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack support ES5 and above. IE8, however, runs ES3, so you’ll need a polyfill to be able to run ES5 code. You can add ES5 shim loader to your Webpack config. Moreover, you should also set NODE_ENV to Production and then It will not throw error for empty descriptor.

```
Object.defineProperty({},'a',{});
```

So, this is how we can overcome this error but the question remains, what should happen if the descriptor is not empty? ie, if value is not provided, get and set are not provided, but configurable, enumerable, and writable are present? and the answer is, it fails silently in IE8 (which is the documented behavior).